# Doctrine MySQL Error 1045 (Using Password: NO) even though there is a password and it's correct

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony

I keep getting this when trying to create a database in Doctrine (I'm using Symfony 3.1.4):

> An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

From what I gather, this error pops up when trying to connect to MySQL when the user has no password or it's incorrect. But this is not my case.

parameters.yml is as follows:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: 8080
database_name: symfony_db
database_user: root
database_password: password
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: secret`
```

And config.yml...

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8`
```

So, nothing seems to be wrong here. MySQL does have a password, and the one in parameters.yml is exactly the same I use in phpmyadmin and used to work when using Laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change your database_host to localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: No dice, got the same result!

Comment: It says "Using password: NO" so I think your configuration is wrong.

Comment: That might be, but where? I admit I skimmed through the config part when installing Symfony, but all it does is build the parameters.yml file that I could edit later, right?

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do, but i'd recheck the port your using. 8080 is by default an HTTP port wherease MySQL uses 3306 as it's default..

Comment: Good guess, but didn't work as well.

Comment: See if the credentials are being overwritten in `config_dev.yml` or `config_prod.yml`

Comment: Nothing about Doctrine in either, so that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to fix it.

As mentioned in the comments, I did skim through the Symfony installation instructions to change it all later in parameters.yml, but what happened was that Symfony didn't do anything new when I change config.yml and parameters.yml, only the initial parameters stood.

And I finally found out why, courtesy of some helpful person on the #symfony IRC channel: while I was changing configurations, **the wrong information I initially inserted during installation was cached**, so all I had to do was to run `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear` on the command line before connecting.